# Error Handling in QPrinter

Tags: qt

When printing to PDF with QTextDocument and QPrinter is there any way of detecting errors (e.g. not being able to write to the PDF file)?
I'm using the following code:

```
QTextDocument document;
QPrinter printer( QPrinter::HighResolution );
printer.setOutputFormat( QPrinter::PdfFormat );
printer.setOutputFileName( filename );
document.print( &printer );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like printerState does return an error when failing to write a file as long as the file name is valid. If the file name is not valid it returns idle.

Answer (score 4):

In the docs you'll find [`QPrinter::printerState`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#printerState). So you can definitely do:

```
if (printer.printerState() == QPrinter::Error)
    // do some error handling
```

I admit that's not a lot work with, as there are only 4 `QPrinter::PrinterState`'s. You might want to do your best to avoid errors in the first place. The [detailed description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#details) in the doc states:

> Note that setting parameters like paper size and resolution on an invalid printer is undefined. You can use `QPrinter::isValid()` to verify this before changing any parameters.

Additionaly, you could check if the filename you are setting already exists using [`QFile::exists`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qfile.html#exists).
Also, when setting it all up you can call and handle [`QPrinter::supportedResolutions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#supportedResolutions), [`QPrinter::supportedPaperSources()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#supportedPaperSources) and [`QPrinter::supportsMultipleCopies()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#supportsMultipleCopies). Of course, printing to PDF you might not have to worry about these.

Comment: I've tried examining printerState but it seems to always be set to idle even when writing the PDF has failed.

Comment: Well, without seeing a bit of code it is going to be hard to say what's wrong. Could you drop a minimum working example of what you are doing? It would make sense to not have an updated PrinterState right away. I am guessing the actual printing will be executed in another thread on your machine and Qt might just wait to hear back from it. All QPrinter does is use your built-in printer drivers (see docs).

Comment: Like [this link](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11356-Safe-checking-the-QPrinter-PrintState-after-printing) suggests you might want to try triggering a timed event shortly after executing the print and then check for the state.

Comment: I've now tried checking the printer state after printing but it never returns anything other than idle. Think I'm going to have to go for a nasty loop checking whether the output file has been modified.